# Showing an error like no user is found even i created the user in pgadmin

Tags: database, postgresql, pgadmin

Here i am trying to create a new database and new role/user to that. I created the database called 'testing' now. And I assigned the role/user called 'precision' to that database.

But my site still showing an error like below:

```
    /usr/local/lib/php/kohana-v.2.3.4/system/libraries/drivers/Database/Pgsql.php [48]:
pg_connect(): Unable to connect to PostgreSQL server: ERROR: No such user: precision
```

If i try the same with anyother database and user then it is working fine.

I am new for Pg-admin and PostgreSQL.  Kindly help and let me know What i did wrong. Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: More information please. Do the two databases (the one where you created the user and the one to which you cannot connect) share hostname and port? What does `SELECT usename FROM pg_user` show?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. **SELECT usename FROM pg_user** returns me the all rolename/ usename of the postgresql of the server. Mine also included with that. the user/role is exist actually. But my code returns the error like above i mentioned. 

Am sorry I could not show you my host. I may tell you what i did if you are not cleared.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe So the actual problem is user/role is exist in my Postgresql. But it is not recognized by the code. I logged in Pgadmin as **root** user. And I created that user/role called **precision**. Root user has permission to create database and roles. 

let me know if anything you need to know.

Comment: Set `log_connections` to `on` on the PostgreSQL server and read the PostgreSQL log file after a failed login attempt. That will tell you what happened.